# Is it bad practice to set my own MongoDB _id from a unique ID of the document?

Tags: php, mongodb

I am receiving and storing an array of JSON objects, like this:

```
$json_assoc_array = array (
    {
        'id' => "unique-id-1",
        'key_one' => "some value",
        'key_two' => "some value",
        'key_three' => "some value"
    },
    {
        'id' => "unique-id-2",
        'key_one' => "some value",
        'key_two' => "some value",
        'key_three' => "some value"
    },
    {
        'id' => "unique-id-3",
        'key_one' => "some value",
        'key_two' => "some value",
        'key_three' => "some value"
    }
);
```

And I'll later be receiving updates to those objects in the same format.  I'll need to update the objects/documents by their `id` field.

When I insert them into MongoDB with a simple `insertMany`, they also get unique MongoDB object `_id`s, so the resulting documents look like this:

```
$json_assoc_array = array (
    {
        '_id' => "5b824c113e2ffc4e7239bfc5"
        'id' => "unique-id-1",
        'key_one' => "some value",
        'key_two' => "some value",
        'key_three' => "some value"
    },
    {
        '_id' => "5b824c1b3e2ffc4e7239caa2"
        'id' => "unique-id-2",
        'key_one' => "some value",
        'key_two' => "some value",
        'key_three' => "some value"
    },
    {
        '_id' => "5b824c1b3e2ffc4e7239caa3"
        'id' => "unique-id-3",
        'key_one' => "some value",
        'key_two' => "some value",
        'key_three' => "some value"
    }
);
```

There will never be another document by the id `unique-id-1`.  So, I am now setting them before originally inserting them, like this:

```
$json_assoc_array = json_decode($data, true);

// Set order MongoDB _id
$json_assoc_array['_id'] = $json_assoc_array['id'];

// Set MongoDB collection
$collection = $mongo->mongo_db_name->collection;

// Insert documents into MongoDB
$result = $collection->insertMany( $json_assoc_array );

// Now when I insert the above documents, they result in this
$json_assoc_array = array (
    {
        '_id' => "unique-id-1"
        'id' => "unique-id-1",
        'key_one' => "some value",
        'key_two' => "some value",
        'key_three' => "some value"
    },
    {
        '_id' => "unique-id-2"
        'id' => "unique-id-2",
        'key_one' => "some value",
        'key_two' => "some value",
        'key_three' => "some value"
    },
    ...
);
```

Is there any reason why this is bad practice?

Should I instead be leaving the `_id` to be set by MongoDB, and use the `id` field to update the existing documents?

Comment: Are you planning on updating the `id` after the document is created? If not, I would use your unique `id` as the `_id` value (which always has a unique index) and avoid adding a separate field. The separate field adds unnecessary overhead by storing duplicate values and maintaining a second unique index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the fact that [`_id` is immutable](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#field-names), you can use whatever you wish, bar of an array.

It even may be to your advantage. With carefully crafted indices and queries, you might be able to benefit from [index intersections (more than one index being used in a query)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-intersection/). This in and of itself gives you more options to model your data efficiently, but let us set this aspect aside for now. The more interesting point is that if you only need a subset of the documents' fields which are covered by indices, you may be able to make the according query "covered" (answered only from indices, which usually are kept in RAM), utilizing an index you can not avoid.

tl;dr: ObjectId is just a construct to be able to provide a globally unique identifier *in case your data does not provide one*. Using something which holds semantic value instead of ObjectId is what I personally consider *best* practice.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that when searching by _id the _id index always covers the query?

Comment: @SergeyKandaurov Yes, but it is not a [covered query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query) in the sense that it is an index-only query. Unless you happen to project `_id` *only*, of course.